# jQuery/JavaScript inquiry about <a> title attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$.get('http://www.roblox.com/', function(data) {
    $(data).find('.member-name-container').children('[title]').each(function() {
        console.log( $(this ).text() );
    });
});
```

I'm trying to get it to find the `<a title='titlehere'></a>` on this piece of code in HTML.

Here is what I'm trying to find the title of;

```
<div class="member-name-container">
    <a class="notranslate" href="/User.aspx?ID=4681012" title="DeltaAddict">DeltaAddict</a>
</div>
```

How would I make it print out the title="DeltaAddict"?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$.get('http://www.roblox.com/',function(data){
    $(data).find('.member-name-container a').each(function() {
        console.log( $( this ).attr('title') )
    })
});
```

Comment: That is what I'm looking for, but when I run the code it doesn't output the <a> title.

Comment: No, I think you may misunderstand. All I want is for it to console.log the attribute 'title', do I really need the .children in there?

Comment: I've updated the example to find all a tags that is sub-elements to .member-name container and then log the title of the a-element. See this fiddle for an example of use: http://jsfiddle.net/7L5vvxt0/

Comment: .children("SelectorHere") will always search for direct children of the node (for which you are calling this method).. but if you want to get all the "anchor tags with title attribute" witin the html markup, you should use .find("a[title]"), and to print the value of any attribute you can use .attr("title") or .prop("title")

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you want :

```
$.get('http://www.roblox.com/',function(data){
$(".member-name-container").children("a").each(function() {
alert($(this).attr( "title" ));
});
});
```